# Why does ob_flush work on apache localhost but not remote?

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I want to use the example below to send updates back to the browser to show progress for long running scripts.

Testing this on the live server it works as expected via localhost but not remote. This is an EC2 windows instance, there is no compression configured and it's not sitting behind Cloudfront or a load balancer, etc.

Both of the following work fine on the server via localhost.

```
public function getProgressTest()
{

  ob_implicit_flush(true);
  ob_end_flush();

  for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {

    sleep(1);
    echo $i . ", ";

  }

}
```

```
public function getProgressTest()
{

  for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {

    sleep(1);
    echo $i . ", ";

    ob_flush();
    flush();

  }

}
```

If anyone has recently experienced a similar issue any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What OS is the localhost server? Is that a Windows machine or nix?

Answer (score 0):

Simply forgot to add the header. Here is the working code:

```
public function getProgressTest()
{
  
  header('Content-Type: text/HTML; charset=utf-8');

  ob_implicit_flush(true);
  ob_end_flush();

  for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {

    sleep(1);
    echo $i . ", ";

  }

}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.